# Put bootstrap label below checkbox?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, bootstrap-4

How do I put the bootstrap label below the checkbox?

```css
.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label::before,
.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label::after {
  width: 1.55rem;
  height: 1.55rem;
}

.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label {
  padding-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-lg">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="delivery-checkbox-18" name="deliveryAddresses[]" value="">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="delivery-checkbox-18">
    fsdfs <br>
    sdfsd <br>
    sdfsdf <br>
    434 sdfsd
    </label>
</div>
```

I get this result

[image: The result I get]

But I want this result

[image: I want this]

If I add more `<br>` first I get this (more space above)

[image]

Comment: Add <br> tag before <label>.

Comment: Have you tried to use the display property? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using bootstrap custom label, if you want the text to appear below the checkbox, you need to override the padding-left of the checkbox container and then add padding top to your label:

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css);
.checkbox-lg {
  padding-left: 0.2rem; /* remove left padding from container (needs 0.2rem to show outline when focused */
}

.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label::before,
.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label::after {
  width: 1.55rem;
  height: 1.55rem;  
  left: 0.2rem; /* this should be the same as the padding left set above so checkbox lines up with content */
}

.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label {
  padding-top: 2rem;  /* this must be more than the height you set above */
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-lg">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="delivery-checkbox-18" name="deliveryAddresses[]" value="">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="delivery-checkbox-18">
    fsdfs <br>
    sdfsd <br>
    sdfsdf <br>
    434 sdfsd
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-lg">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="delivery-checkbox-18" name="deliveryAddresses[]" value="">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="delivery-checkbox-18">
      <br>
    fsdfs <br>
    sdfsd <br>
    sdfsdf <br>
    434 sdfsd
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You should always explain your anwser and use a code snippet (ctrl + m) to validate that your solution is working. Just by posting an unexplained codeline, the OP now needs to put a lot of efford to udnerstand what you did and how to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve that is to convert the checkbox to a block level element in CSS: `input[type='checkbox'] { display: block; }`

```css
.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label::before,
.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label::after {
  width: 1.55rem;
  height: 1.55rem;
}

.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label {
  padding-left: 6px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-lg">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="delivery-checkbox-18" name="deliveryAddresses[]" value="">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="delivery-checkbox-18">fsdfs<br>
sdfsd <br>
sdfsdf <br>
434 sdfsd
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: if you see closely  `block` is making text below the checkbox but also adding extra space before `fsdfs` .

Comment: because of the label. The label adds a space before the way it is programmed (padding left: 6px;). Not because the checkbox is a block level element.

Comment: Stackoverflow can't be using bootstrap in snippet. Your solution works if I remove custom-control-input and custom-control-label but not if I use that bootstrap classes.

Comment: @Xtreme you can add custom css below the bootstrap css then it apllies just fine and overwrites the bootstrap css. alternativly add it as inline style to give it a higher specifity weight. And of course you can use the bootstrap css in a stack snipept. You just need to link the bootstrap library.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `<br>` tag just after your `<label>` tag works for me. See below HTML code:

```css
.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label::before,
.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label::after {
  width: 1.55rem;
  height: 1.55rem;
}

.checkbox-lg .custom-control-label {
  padding-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-lg">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="delivery-checkbox-18" name="deliveryAddresses[]" value="">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="delivery-checkbox-18"><br>
    fsdfs <br>
    sdfsd <br>
    sdfsdf <br>
    434 sdfsd
    </label>
</div>
```